# ASP.NET GridView width will not stay at 100% after binding to SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and want its width to remain at 100%. It looks fine in design view, so I'm assuming something about binding with a SqlDataAdapter resets the width to suit the data, but I would like it to stay at 100%. The width ends up being whatever it needs to be to support the bound data.

I'm admittedly new to all of this, so I'm sure the answer will be more apparent to all of you than it is to me.

```
<div id="X" class="In-lineControl" style="width:100%">
     <asp:GridView ID="XGV" runat="server" CssClass="GridView" BorderStyle="Groove">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#B4C2E0" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6C88C4" ForeColor="White" />
     </asp:GridView>
</div>

XData.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable XDT = new DataTable();
XData.Fill(XDT);
XGV.DataSource = XDT;
XGV.DataBind();

.GridView{
width:100%;
}

.In-lineControl{
display:block;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[image: The GridView should extend its width out to 100% of the white area. It does in the design view, but the width changes after binding a SqlDataAdapter in the code behind.]

Comment: Need css definitions and rendered output.

Comment: Sorry, should have included that. See the edit.

Comment: by rendered output I meant the html served to the client

Comment: Have u tried actually setting grid's width property (not CSS style). e.g.`<asp:GridView width="100%" ID="XGV" runat="server" ...` ?

Comment: Yes, had no effect. The issue has to be that DataBind is somehow altering the width of the GridView. I reassigned the CssClass after the DataBind is complete and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the CssClass to the GridView in the code behind after DataBind fixed the issue.

The code behind ended up looking like this:

```
XData.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable XDT = new DataTable();
XData.Fill(XDT);
XGV.DataSource = XDT;
XGV.DataBind();
XGV.CssClass = "GridView";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the CssClass `GridView` and see if there is a width set there.

Comment: Sorry, should have included that. I've edited my post. It only contains width:100%.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you define your bound columns and fields within your grid based on your datasource and provide the width for each.

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-Width="25%"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

AutoGeneratedColumns is true by default so when you bind to your data, it seems to be resizing each column based on the data inside it. Thus, resizing your entire grid.

Comment: The GridView contains different data depending on user input, so I'm not sure defining the columns and fields beforehand will work.